# In Grails GSP, what is the equivalent to Spring MVC's <input name="entity.list[0].field">?

Tags: grails

I'm coming from a Spring MVC background on a new Grails app.  I have an object that contains a list of dependent objects.  On the create and edit screen, I want to edit that object and its list of objects at the same time.  In Spring MVC, you could use special names to bind the form fields to items in a list.  Example:

```
Entity { String name, List items }

<form:input name="entity.items[0].value" value="${entity.items[0].value}"/>
```

I've tried similar variations in my GSP create and edit forms, but no luck.

Comment: Marking the question as answered, although it doesn't work for the grails form tags, only raw HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this with  tag (is it a Java taglib?), but what you are doing is along the right path.  I don't think you need the entity in there, the name should be just "items[0].value"

Here is some code I have that does what you need (using HTML input tag):

```
<input type="text" name="subItems[0].date"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a Spring WebMVC taglib.

And you are right, that works!  My problem is that I was trying to use the gsp tag like so: <g:textField name="subItems[0].date"/>  and this throws a runtime exception.

Any ideas on how to make it work for <g:textField/> ?